# Laravel Export Excel doesn't return an excel file

Tags: excel, laravel-5

I want to export excel. This is my controller code:

```php
public function export() {
    $data['stok'] = Stokbarang::with('products')->get();
    $tgl = thisDay();
    return Excel::create('Stok'.$tgl, function($excel) use ($index) {
        $excel->sheet('New sheet', function($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->loadView('panel.stok.excel',$data);
        });
    })->export('xls');
}
```

But it doesn't return an Excel file. It returns something like this instead:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ?

Comment: yes sir.. @RomanBobrik

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 3.1 but now downgrade ito 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. This is because a redundant route between the resource root which is return a datatable and my export route.